# I want to grep [[:punct:]] and [[:alnum:]] in list without any other characters

Tags: regex, grep

I need help to grep Alphanumeric [[:alnum:]] & Special Characters [[:punct:]] from wordlist without any other characters.

for example, this is the list:

```
love
great2
pl@ce
&rt
joHn
&^~%$@!$#)(_-+
hearʥ
ʯbattle
fiʬeld
```

i need regular expression to print all the list & exclude these characters "ʥ - ʯ - ʬ" from the last three words and print them like that as output:

```
love
great2
pl@ce
&rt
joHn
&^~%$@!$#)(_-+
hear
battle
field
```

Thanks, wish you all great day :)

i've tried that linux command but i didn't get the expected output

```
grep -E -o --text "[[:punct:]]*[[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]]*[[:punct:]]" list.txt > Final.txt
```

Comment: When there are multiple matches on a line, `grep -o` puts each match on a different output line. It would be better to use `sed` to replace what you don't want with an empty string, then you'll get the updated line in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is not the right tool because `-o` option will break down each matched input on a separate line.

Better to use a tool like `gnu-sed`, where you can remove all non-ascii characters from input:

```bash
sed 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' file

love
great2
pl@ce
&rt
joHn
&^~%$@!$#)(_-+
hear
battle
field
```

Similarly using `perl`:

```bash
perl -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]+//g' file

love
great2
pl@ce
&rt
joHn
&^~%$@!$#)(_-+
hear
battle
field
```

Just to elaborate above point about `grep`, here is the output:

```bash
grep -oP "[[:ascii:]]+" file

love
great2
pl@ce
&rt
joHn
&^~%$@!$#)(_-+
hear
battle
fi
eld
```

Comment: perl command works perfect, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, an `awk` -

```
$: awk '{ gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,"") }1' file
love
great2
pl@ce
&rt
joHn
&^~%$@!$#)(_-+
hear
battle
field
```